# Firebase Notifications to iOS topic via HTTP POST request

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So we are using Firebase to send notifications to our users on our iOS app. It works great in the console, but now we are looking to allow a few more people to send notifications, and we don't really want them signing into Firebase to do that. One solution we came up with is to put a form on our website and let them sign in and send notifications from there, but we can't get it to work. The code below is a stripped down version of what we have right now. It uses the cloud messaging API to send an HTTP POST request to a specific topic and Firebase responds with a `message_id`, however no message is delivered on any of the devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input id="title"></input>
    <input id="message"></input>
    <button>Submit</button>
</body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $("button").click(function () {
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();

            var param = {
              "to" : "/topics/myTopic",
              "content_available" : true,
              "notification" : {
                "title" : title,
                "body" : message
               }
            };

           $.ajax({
             url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
             type: "POST",
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'key=<myKey>', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             data: JSON.stringify(param),
             success: function () {
               alert("success");
             },
             error: function(error) {
               alert("error: "+error);
             }
           });
         });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

### **Solution:**

After we played around with it a bit more, we found that `content_available` should really be false in order to actually display a notification in our app. We also made sure to implement jQuery variables correctly. You can see our improved script for handling everything below.

```
$("button").click(function () {
   // Grab the input values
   $title = $("#title").val();
   $message = $("#message").val();

   // Verify that the message is not left empty
   if ( $message.length < 2 ){
       // Message is empty
       return;
   }

   // Create the JSON object
   var paramaters = {
     "to" : "/topics/test",
     "content_available" : false,
     "notification" : {
       "title" : $title,
       "body" : $message
      }
   };

   // Send request
   $.ajax({
     url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
     type: "POST",
     headers: { 'Authorization': 'key=$key', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
     data: JSON.stringify(paramaters),
     success: function (e) {
       // Process succeeded
       console.log(e);
     },
     error: function(error) {
       // Display error message
     }
   });
});
```

We also made sure that our server keys were not included directly in our code as Frank mentioned in his comment. Everything now works and we are successfully receiving notifications.

Comment: Please **don't** put your server key (which is needed to send messages) on a public web site. Somebody will find it and can then send messages to your users on your behalf.

Comment: Have you tried adding `priority` parameter with `high` value?

Comment: Yes, we have tried the priority parameter and to no avail.